# Convert excel to Json file using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to convert attached sample csv to json file. It is workng fine for  single server but finding issue when it is more than 1 server
[excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgX07.png)

```
,How many servers are required?*  ,3,,,

,,,,,

,,,,,

,,,Server 1,Server 2,Server 3

,,,,,

1,OS Type*,,Windows,Unix,Windows

,,,,,

2,OS Version*,,Windows Server 2019,RHEL 7.9,Windows Server 2019

,,,,,

3,Server environment*,,Non-production,Non-production,Non-production
```

the output I'm expecting will be a json file as shown below.

```
[
 Server 1{
      
      "OSType": "Windows",
      "OSVersion": "Windows Server 2019",
      "Serverenvironment": "Non-production",
      "Storage(EBS-GP3)-Rootvolume": "100",
      "Storage(EBS-GP3)-additionalstorage": "NA",
      "FileSystem1": "NA",
      "Volume1": "NA",
      "FileSystem2": "NA",
},
Server 2{
      "OSType": "Unix",
      "OSVersion": "RHEL 8.5",
      "Serverenvironment": "Non-production",
      "Storage(EBS-GP3)-Rootvolume": "120",
      "Storage(EBS-GP3)-additionalstorage": "NA",
      "FileSystem1": "NA",
      "Volume1": "NA",
      "FileSystem2": "NA",
}

so on... ]
```

Below is the code that is working if it is single server data but not for multiple server information. Any suggestion will be of great help.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Downloads/One_server_2022_06_14_18_05_03.csv',engine ='python',encoding= 'unicode_escape', names=['S1', 'S2', 'S3'])

df_Notnull= df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
df_new=df_Notnull[df_Notnull['S1'].notna()]
df_new = df_new.fillna("NA")
df_new = df_new.replace("\u00a0"," ", regex=True)
df_new['S1'] = df_new['S1'].str.replace(' ', '')
df_new['S1'] = df_new['S1'].str.replace('*', '')
df_new['S1'] = df_new['S1'].str.replace('?', '')
df_dict=dict(list(zip(df_new.S1,df_new.S3)))
import json 
with open('C:/Users/user/Downloads/TEST.json', 'w') as file:
    
    #json.dumps(json_object, file, indent=4, separators=(',',':') , sort_keys=False)
    #json.dumps(json_object, file)
    file.write(json.dumps(df_dict,indent=4))
```

Comment: Put a few (3-5) lines of the scv file in the question.

Comment: Hi @СергейКох , Thanks for considering. I have updated sample csv.

Comment: To fully reproduce your question, you can do this                                                  
```with open("C:/Users/Downloads/One_server_2022_06_14_18_05_03.csv", 'r') as f:
      for i in range(5):
      print(f.readline()) ```                                                                                               
 and paste the printout as code in the question.

Comment: In this scenario I'm trying to convert excel/CSV file to Json format. I tried your code, but the output is a comma separated value. @СергейКох

Comment: Yes, that's how the csv file looks from the inside.

Comment: I have updated the csv output in question @СергейКох. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


# We read the file and remove empty rows and columns.
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv').dropna(how='all', axis=1).dropna(how='all')

# We remove the unnecessary column and replace the remaining none with 0.
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1).fillna(0)

# We replace the indexes and names of rows and columns with the required ones and delete the now unnecessary ones.
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
df = df.rename(index=df[0]).drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1)

# We write the result to a file with the required orientation.
result = df.to_json('test.json', orient="columns")

{"Server 1":{"OS Type*":"Windows","OS Version*":"Windows Server 2019","Server environment*":"Non-production"},
"Server 2":{"OS Type*":"Unix","OS Version*":"RHEL 7.9","Server environment*":"Non-production"},
"Server 3":{"OS Type*":"Windows","OS Version*":"Windows Server 2019","Server environment*":"Non-production"}}
```

The result is not exactly the same, but close.

Comment: Awesome!! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot @Сергей Кох. Only thing is that the output Json data is in a single line which should have been in separate lines like the example json data.